# How must be data types of a structure in Delphi based in other structure in C?

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi code where i want send some data (using [`DeviceIoControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) api) to a kernel driver, driver receives these data in a structure that already is defined like follow:

```
typedef struct MyData
{
    DWORD64 pid;
    WCHAR path[200];
}
```

Then, how must be the equivalent in Delphi (with data types right)?

thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Given your recent questions I believe you know how to translate this.

Comment: A record with two members. The first is a `DWORD64` (which you could rename `UInt64`) and the second is a static array of size 200 and type `WHCAR` (which you could rename `char` in Delphi 2009+).

Comment: Or you could use Windows unit and use the same type names. @Andreas You'd always translate WCHAR to WideChar if you had to pick one of the three native character types.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, thank you. But `WCHAR` (in C) not is different of `Char` (in Delphi)?

Comment: Not in modern Unicode Delphi. Why don't you do some research. There are plenty of resources to tell you what these types are. Surely you can work this out if you just make some effort.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, ok. Now that i saw that he wrote *" `in Delphi 2009+` "*, sorry.

Comment: Just use those type names verbatim.

Comment: @Andreas: the best thing you can do when converting is to stay as close as possible to the original. Generally types like WCHAR are already defined in the Winapi somewhere, and these definitions are generally correct. If there is no such definition, then, to stay independent of version, translate it as a fixed size type, IOW `WideChar`, in this case. That should work in D2007 and older as well as in D2009 and newer.

Comment: @Rudy: I completely agree with you. That's why I offered the more familiar types only within parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how must be the equivalent in Delphi (with data types right)?

Like this:

```
type
  MyData = record
    pid: UInt64;
    path: array[0..199] of WideChar;
  end;
```